# How to query db for an entry using Identity UserId in OnGetAsync method

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, razor-pages, ef-core-3.1, razor-pages-crud

So I have a Razor pages web app I am currently developing using the latest versions of EF Core, ASP.NET, ASP.NET Identity, etc.

What I'm trying to do is get my current logged in User using the OnGetAsync method of one of my Razor pages, but I also only want to retrieve the latest data entry created by the logged in user to display with my Razor page .cshtml file.

I've tried implementing the UserManager techniques found here in stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I keep getting the 2 following errors on my line of code where I'm comparing my logged in user with the userid column of the db entity table in question :

*With the following code setup*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var userId = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        string UserId = Convert.ToString(userId);


        if (UserId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        ForecastCinema = await _context.ForecastsCinema
            .Where(f => f.UserId == userId);
    }
```

**"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'AppUser'".**

AppUser being the name of the User table in my database for .Net Identity

*And with another type of code formatting, the other error just below*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var userId = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        string UserId = Convert.ToString(userId);


        if (UserId == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        ForecastCinema = await _context.ForecastsCinema
            .Where(f => f.UserId == UserId);
    }
```

**"IQueryable doest not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

Could someone please please please help me see what's going on here? I've tried "converting" my UserManager claim to a string but to no prevail, it doesn't work. I've attached the code of the method in question just below for reference. Thanks in advance for the help and insight fellow coders :)

Answer (score 0):

"Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'AppUser'"

I would expect as the error message says, it literally means you are comparing two types using ==.

First thing I see is that you are comparing f.UserId with userId, which you got from

```
await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

This seems giving you User object, not just Id.

"IQueryable doest not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

As what the error message says, it's not Async Task type so you can't use "await" in front of it.  Try without await for querying the result. I believe it's refering to this code:

```
await _context.ForecastsCinema
        .Where(f => f.UserId == UserId);
```